# Why is the Array undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, callback

When I alert my array "markerArray" outside the geocoder-function it says it's undefined.
Can't figure out why? Is there a way to get the values from the array outside the function?

```
var markerArray = new Array();
for(var i in opts.markers)
{
    address = opts.markers[i].address;
    //alert(opts.markers[i].icon);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
        markerArray[i] = marker;

    });

}
alert(markerArray[0].position);
```

Comment: is `opts.markers` an array or an object?

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but don't use `for ... in` to enumerate arrays: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#array.general

Comment: Can you insert console.log(markerArray) just after markerArray[i] = marker; and before alert? And show results. Output of console.log you can monitor in firebug or other javascript developer tool for browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it's not `markerArray` that it's complaining about, but `markerArray[0]` that's undefined.

You're calling an asynchronous API using functions you create in a loop. Those functions are closures. They each have an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, *not* a copy of the value as it was when the function was defined. So all of the functions use the last `i` value from the loop, because none of them runs until the loop is over. So if the last value `i` has in the loop is `5`, say, then **all** of the functions will use `5`.

Also, you're then doing your `alert` too soon, before any of the callbacks has a chance to run. You'll need to do whatever final processing you need to do in one of the callbacks (you can use a counter to know when they've all happened).

You can fix both the `markerArray` problem and the premature `alert` like this:

```
var markerArray = new Array();
var callcounter = 0;
for(var i in opts.markers)
{
    address = opts.markers[i].address;
    //alert(opts.markers[i].icon);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    ++callcounter;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, buildCallback(i));

}

function buildCallback(index) {
    return function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
        markerArray[index] = marker;
        if (--callcounter === 0) {
            // This was the last outstanding call
            alert(markerArray[0]); // Always assuming there was a `0` in `opts.markers`
        }
    };
}
```

Now, the callbacks are closures over the `index` argument you pass into the `buildCallback` function, instead of the `i` variable in your main loop. We do the alert when we're done with all the callbacks, which we know because of the `callcounter` *(see note below if your "race condition" radar is going off)*.

All of this is because of the way closures work. They're not complicated (in fact, I wrote a blog post about them called [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)), but there are some things you need to firmly understand to "get" why they do what they do.

Separately: You're using `for..in` to loop through `opts.markers`, which I suspect is an array. If it is, then that code has issues you need to solve. `for..in` is not for looping through the *indexes* of an *array*, it's for looping through the *property names* of an *object*. [More here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) You either need to add some checks to your `for..in` loop, or just use a boring old-fashioned `for` loop.

---

Re the `counter`: To anyone used to multi-threaded programming, my simple "increment it when scheduling, decrement it when processing" logic looks like it sets up a race condition (what if the first one gets called back before the second one is scheduled?). But it's not a race condition in JavaScript on browsers, because JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (or if you use [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), kind of cooperatively multi-threaded). There is no pre-emptive multi-threading here. None of the callbacks will ever be called until they have *all* been scheduled.

---

**Off-topic**: Although `var markerArray = new Array();` works just fine, I'd recommend `var markerArray = [];` instead. It's shorter; for various reasons the implementation can optimize it a bit more (not that it really matters); and there's no possibility that someone has shadowed the `Array` symbol. Similarly, any time you want just a blank object, use `{}` instead of `new Object()`.